# $(this).attr("name") not working with $.post

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code on a simple form. Please can you tell me why this code works

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(":input").focus(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
                $.post("ajax-validation.php", { "username" : $(this).val() },
                function(data){
                    $("#display").html(data);
                });
                this.lastValue = this.value;
            };
        });
    });

});
```

and this not?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(":input").focus(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
                $.post("ajax-validation.php", { $(this).attr("name") : $(this).val() },
                function(data){
                    $("#display").html(data);
                });
                this.lastValue = this.value;
            };
        });
    });

});
```

It's a very strange thing!!

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: I wonder if: `{ $(this).attr("name") :`  changed to `{'"'+ $(this).attr("name") +'"':`  would work

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not. `$(this)` has no context where you put it. You need to cache it and reuse it. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(":input").focus(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            var el = $(this), theName = el.attr("name"), data = {};
            data[theName] = el.val();
            if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
                
                $.post("ajax-validation.php", data , function(data) {
                    $("#display").html(data);
                });
                //console.log(el.attr("name"), el.val());
                this.lastValue = this.value;
            };
        });
    });

});
```

CODE CORRECTED! It appears that the use of methods (even if it returns a string) is not allowed. So I put it in another variable and used it there. **[Tested and works. (see the requests with dev tools or firebug)](http://jsfiddle.net/KC3cC/)**

CODE CORRECTED! AGAIN! It appears as though `$.post` doesn't like variables (it treats them as strings), so I define the data object outside the `$.post` method, and pass it in. Works like a charm.

### Important points to consider

- The code is **correct** but not **robust**, meaning, it will work exactly as you asked in the answer, but it might, and it will choke your server with endless requests in case of an attack. You should:

  - Make a timer (with `setTimeout` to throttle the requests (only after 3-4 seconds with no editing).
  - Make sure you're safe on the server-side, don't allow many requests from the same connection. Use the connection info in conjunction with a global counter (saved on a database or a text file) to determine if the user is abusing your system, and block it.
- You should, (in my opinion) have a validate button (or link, or whatever) to check whether the input is valid, rather then automatically validating on keypress.

Comment: You should add a `var` before `el`, or declare el somewhere above, so it doesn't become a global.

Comment: this will be fun once you have multiple inputs that can get focus repeatedly.

Comment: Indeed. The code is not robust. It will kill your server in case of an attack. I'll add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Truth It's still not working...
I copied/pasted your code, but it works only if I write "username" instead of name.

Comment: @Truth Now the problem is that the requests are being sent, but ajax-validation.php doesn't recognize the variable $_POST['username'] and I don't know why...

Comment: @WeContest Hmmmmmmmmm. Very interesting. It seems like you can't pass variables directly to the `$.post`. I've corrected my code and tested it locally. It will work.

Comment: @Truth Epic! Now, please, could you explain me why this happens and what do "data = {}" and "data[theName] = el.val()" mean?

Comment: Sure. I've noticed that you can't pass variables directly to `$.post`, so you construct an object (namely, `data`), and put it there, then pass that to `$.post`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
            $.post("ajax-validation.php", { $(this).attr("name") : $(this).val() },
```

Try

```
            var hash = {};
            hash[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
            $.post("ajax-validation.php", hash,
```

Answer (score -3):

$(this).attr("name") is an object not a string which is what that is expecting you to provide in your post. try $(this).attr("name").value or $(this).attr("name").val(), can't remember which but one of those should work for you.

Comment: just... wrong... I rarely downvote answers, but you should've seen this one coming.

Comment: You never used jQuery, did you? `.attr()` and `.prop()` both return a plain value (attr always a string, prop might be a boolean rd integer, too) when used to *get* a value.

Comment: We Contest why yould you even try his suggestion after seeing the comments and downvotes on this ?

Comment: No need to do that just go straight to the documentation http://api.jquery.com/attr/ it will save you some time.